# How do I ack a message with GCP Cloud PubSub (push subscription) <-> Cloud Run?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm using GCP PubSub (push subscription to be precisely), and Cloud Run to execute subscribed messages.

Recently I've noticed that Cloud Run executes a same message for five times.

I see there is a retry policy for a subscription which its message has been unhandled (or mishandled), but Cloud Run clearly is giving 200 OK response.

So it seems that sending 200 OK response is not enough, but I cannot find a way to send ack sign properly.

Here's the code to publish message.

```js
function publish(message: string) {
  const pubsub = new PubSub({ projectId: 'my-project' });

  const dataBuffer = Buffer.from(message);
  const topicName = 'my-topic';

  pubsub
    .topic(topicName)
    .publish(dataBuffer)
    .then((messageId) => {
      console.log(`Message ${messageId} published`);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}

publish(JSON.stringify({ foo : 'bar' }));
```

And here's the code of Cloud Run.

```js
// express app

app.post('/run', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const body = req.body.message ? Buffer.from(req.body.message.data, 'base64').toString() : req.body;
    // req.body came out to be "{"foo":"bar"}"

    const deliveredMessage = JSON.parse(body);

    // do something

    // Do I have to do something like message.ack() here?
    return res.status(200).end();
  } catch (e) {
    return res.status(502).end();
  }
});
```

These are example responses of Cloud Run retrying.
[image]

Here's a graph of unacked messages at that time.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is your cloud run app running when you did the post?

Because there is a timeout for the messages waiting in the queue, maybe pub/sub is resending the messages before you start to consuming it.

Another thing you can try is putting the response at the first line, like:

```
app.post('/run', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        res.status(200)
        ...
```